# What happens when I assign static object to non static object?

Tags: java, static

I wonder what happens when I assign a static object to non-static object ?
For example:

```
public class Test{
   public void test(){
      BoneCp cp=BoneCpLoad.getBoneCpPool();
   }
}

public class BoneCpLoad{
    private static BoneCpPool pool =new BoneCpPool();
    public static BoneCp getBoneCpPool(){
        return pool;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really a question...

Comment: You're not. `getBoneCpPool()` returns a new object...

Comment: `new BoneCpPool` created an object ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static objects actually don't exist.

In this case static keyword is referred to getBoneCpPool() method. This is perfectly legal and the static method returns an instance of BonceCp object.

static modifier keyword can be applied to methods, and denotes methods that not belong to a particular instance of a class, but to the class itself.

static modifier keyword can be applied to fields too (actually are static reference to objects). In this case denotes fields that not belong to a particular instance of a class, but are share between all class instances of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really assigning a static object to a non-static object.

```
BoneCp cp = BoneCpLoad.getBoneCpPool();
```

This line is equivalent to

```
BoneCp cp = new BoneCpPool();
```

Which is just a normal instantiation of an object.

Answer (score 0):

This whole question is based on a false premise.

In Java, there is no such thing as a `static` object.  All objects live in the heap and their lifetime is determined by reachability.

There *is* such a thing as a `static` variable.  However, nothing special happens when you assign a reference to a `static` variable.  The variable now just contains a reference to the object.  Similarly, nothing special happens when you assign a reference in a `static` variable to any other kind of variable.